# Stucture across multiple files

Tags: c#, class, struct

I'm making a simple game that has Stats(strength, intelligence, charisma...) and Skills(Mining,Swim,Ride...). These structures are organized in class `Types`.

I want to reach those structures across all the files. In C++ I could just include the class and use the struct Stats, but I can't do the same in C#.

Is there a way to make this work?

This is my simplified code

```
public class Types{
    public struct stats{
        float str;
        float con;
        float inte;
    }

    public struct skill{
        float mining;
    }
}

public class NPC{
    stats baseStats;
    skill skills;
    string name;
    float hunger;
    float necessity;
    short hp;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want them to be defined as part of Types?  If you want to share them across other objects, wouldn't it make more sense to define them at the namespace level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the structs are nested inside the class Types you need to prefix the declaration of the structs instances with the nesting class name

```
public class NPC
{
    Types.stats baseStats;
    Types.skill skills;
    string name;
    float hunger;
    float necessity;
    short hp;
}
```

Now, if you need to use these types between different namespaces you need to add the appropriate using at the beginning of the file.

```
namespace MyTypes
{
    public class Types
    {
        public struct stats
        {
            float str;
            float con;
            float xxx;
        }

        public struct skill
        {
            float mining;
        }
    }
}
.....


using MyTypes;
namespace MyNPC
{
    public class NPC
    {
        Types.stats baseStats;
        Types.skill skills;
        string name;
        float hunger;
        float necessity;
        short hp;
    }
}
```

Moreover, if the types are in different projects files you need to add the reference to the relative project that contains the declarations.